# Basic classifier and BackPropagation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, backpropagation

I'm following the course on Machine Learning from Coursera and I just had an interrogation.

[Multiple classifier making a xor classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jrVD.png)

On this picture we can see that in order to make a xor classifier we build other smaller classifiers which are trained with linearly separable gate.

So each classifier has a job (for example AND, OR, etc) defined and the network must be trained for this task.

But in a bigger neural net it's impossible to define a task for each neuron (or classifier).

So my question is : Is this the task of the Back-Propogation algorithm (in addition to the fact that it is used to update the weight) ?

Comment: Not a `python` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

If someone is wondering the same thing, yes it is the case.
The backprop algorithm makes "smaller linear solvable" per each neuron (or classifier).